# Is $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ dense in saturated elementarily extensions of the reals?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, first-order-logic, model-theory, geometric-topology

Suppose $\mathcal{A} = \langle A, <, +, \cdot \rangle$ is a $\aleph_1$-saturated elementarily extension of the real field.

Is $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ dense in $SL(2,A)$?

In compact groups one can find subgroups with infinitesimal entries, but is it still possible in $SL(2,A)$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun The second question is precisely context for the first question

Comment: hi Luis. just to make sure, you mean here that the topology on $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is given by the subspace topology as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: @Atticus Stonestrom. Exactly, everywhere there is the Euclidean topology induced by the order

Comment: I don't see how it could possibly be. Let $X$ be any element of $SL(2,A)$ with a non-Archimedean entry (e.g. $\begin{bmatrix}\epsilon & 0\\0 & {1\over\epsilon}\end{bmatrix}$ for $\epsilon$ an infinitesimal). Then unless I'm misunderstanding the topology, there is an open neighborhood of $X$ not containing any "standard" element.

Comment: I'll concede that, @Luis. I'm sorry.

Comment: You are all right. Stupid question. I'll delete it

Comment: I think it's quite a reasonable question, and worth leaving up if you're open to it! maybe @NoahSchweber can write his comment as an answer

Answer (score 6):

*Turning my comment into an answer:*

No, it's not. In fact, every "new" element of $SL(2,A)$ will have a neighborhood missing all of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ - and this uses merely the non-Archimedeanness of $A$.

Suppose $X\in M_2(A)\setminus M_2(\mathbb{R})$ (so $X$ has at least one non-real entry). Let $\epsilon$ be a "small enough" infinitesimal - specifically, let $\epsilon$ be smaller than (the absolute value of) the difference between each finite non-real entry $x$ of $X$ and the real part of $x$. The ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $X$ contains no elements of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Now just make sure the determinant of $X$ is $1$. For example, fixing an infinitesimal $\delta$ we could use $$\begin{bmatrix}\delta & 0\\0 & {1\over\delta}\end{bmatrix}$$ (we could use $\epsilon=\delta^2$ as our corresponding radius).

EDIT: as Adayah observes, this in fact shows that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is nowhere dense in $SL(2,A)$. As a further point of interest it's not hard to show that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is closed as well (see [their answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4427849/28111)).

Comment: I don't get the last comment. Your answer shows precisely that $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is a proper closed subset of $SL(2, A)$, but doesn't show that it is nowhere dense.

Answer (score 3):

It's the opposite - $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is closed in $SL(2, A)$ and has empty interior, so it is nowhere dense.

To see it is closed, first note that $\mathbb{R}$ is closed in $A$. Indeed: take any $\alpha \in A \setminus \mathbb{R}$. If $\alpha$ is unbounded (greater than $r$ for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$), then $(-\infty, \frac{\alpha}{2})$ or $(\frac{\alpha}{2}, \infty)$ is a neighborhood of $\alpha$ disjoint from $\mathbb{R}$. Otherwise $\alpha = r + \varepsilon$ for some $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and infinitesimal $\varepsilon$, and then $\left( \alpha-\frac{|\varepsilon|}{2}, \alpha+\frac{|\varepsilon|}{2} \right)$ is a neighborhood of $\alpha$ disjoint from $\mathbb{R}$.

It follows that $M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ is closed in $M_{2 \times 2}(A)$, so

$$SL(2, \mathbb{R}) = M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \cap SL(2, A)$$

is closed in $SL(2, A)$.

To see that it has empty interior, take any $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ and its neighborhood. If $ad \neq 0$, choosing sufficiently small $\delta, \varepsilon \in A \setminus \mathbb{R}$ such that $(a+\varepsilon)(d+\delta) = ad$, we get that $\begin{pmatrix} a+\varepsilon & b \\ c & d+\delta \end{pmatrix}$ is in the neighborhood but not in $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$. If $ad = 0$, then $bc = -1$ and we can apply the same method to $b$ and $c$.